# Alert after 11th comma in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert when user enter comma (,) 11th time. How can I do this with jQuery or js?

```
<input class='myprofiletags' name='my_profile_tags' value='<?php echo $my_profile_tags; ?>' placeholder="" />
```

What I am doing:

```
jQuery('.myprofiletags').keyup(function()
{
  if( jQuery(this).val().indexOf(',') !== -1 )
  {
      alert('No more text allowed');
  }
}
```

This script above always alerts, even when I press and character after one comma.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use a variable the increment its value as user enter `,` and read its value whenever user enters `,` if value exceeds 11 show a alert

Comment: @Kartikeya: What if I use backspace

Comment: @Jai: Do you even know what `indexOf` does?

Comment: Guessing something to do with **!== -1**

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen heeheehee. i got this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regular expression will handle this...

```
jQuery('.myprofiletags').keypress(function(e)
{
    if (jQuery(this).val().match(/,/g).length > 10)
    {
        e.preventDefault();  // stops the keypress occuring
        alert('No more text allowed');
    }
});
```

I also changed it to use `keypress` stopped further entry as your example code would alert the user, but not actually stop them entering further text.

**jsfiddle example...**

http://jsfiddle.net/3sah4xsm/

Comment: yes u were absolutely right i have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Split by comma, and alert if there are more than 10:

```
jQuery(this).val().split(',').length > 10
```

Comment: Why? It's supposed to allow 10 items.

Comment: @Scimonster is correct; 10 commas would mean there's 11 parts of the array, so `> 10` is correct.

Comment: @callumacrae Suppose there are no commas; the `.length` will return `1`. Apply mathematical induction.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Induction isn't needed. Just test it.